# Running xunit.console on ASP.NET Core Targeting NET451

Tags: asp.net-core, xunit, xunit.net

I've been building an ASP.NET Core library targeting NET451, DNX451 and DNXCORE50. In order to test the library, xUnit.net is used. Within Visual Studio 2015, all targets are fine to run unit tests. However, I found that, with command line, NET451 is tricky to run unit tests.

I can run `dnx test` command for both targeting DNX451 and DNXCORE50. But the problem is, as NET451 is not DNX, I can't run `dnx test` for testing. Instead, I should execute `xunit.console.exe` for testing. Unfortunately, if I run the command, `xunit.console.exe MyProject.Test.dll`, it requires all dependent package libraries to be copied into the same directory as `MyProject.Test.dll`; otherwise, `xunit.console.exe` won't work. That makes sense to me because a project targeting NET451 is supposed to be built on `.csproj`, not `.xproj`.

I wonder if I'm doing the correct approach or not. If my approach is OK, I also wonder if there is a way to copy all those dependencies into the same directory automatically. My `xUnit.net` version is `2.2.0-beta1-build3239`.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left an issue on https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/809 and got a response from them.

`xunit.console.exe` is not designed to use like this. Brad Wilson, one of the author of xUnit.net library, clarified that and also recommended using `.xproj` only for targeting DNX.

HTH